# QML suitable for building a text editor?

Tags: qt, syntax-highlighting, qml

Is QML suitable for building a text editor with syntax highlighting (and maybe code folding)? Do you know of any text editors built using QML?

Comment: You may find http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-textedit.html useful

Comment: Hi, Jamie. Have succeeded to create an editor with QML or C++ ?

Comment: @Kakadu: gave up that project. Looked for another language as C++ seems slow to compile for this type of project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For building the whole editor UI: menus, buttons, file dialogs, it is totally up to the task.

As for exactly the main editor component that shows text, highlights, folding and stuff, technically QML could do it, but to my understanding you'd want to do it in C++ and just expose that C++ component to QML UI.

You will likely need to build the TextEdit component from scratch anyway and you can optimize C++ way more and QML isn't exactly made for the low level graphics/text nuances such as deciding how many pixels exactly to scroll the text on a new line or how to load bit-by-bit and show bit-by-but when you open a huge file. These things are possible with [mostly] QML, but unless you are building something simple, I suppose you'll want to just to C++ side for the main text editing component. And for OS-related operations such as file reading.

Comment: Do you know any starting points I could use for building the TexEdit component from scratch?

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond me for providing any good advice. I'd probably start by examining how the built-in text edits are built.

Answer (score 1):

The [LimeText](http://limetext.org/) editor has a [QML frontend](https://github.com/limetext/lime-qml).

Comment: I'm sorry but... looks like you have put the wrong website of LimeText editor. Not limetext.org, the right website should be limetext.github.io.